# how to use dll of same name but different version from different locations in same application?

Tags: c#, dll, versioning

We are trying to program a couple of plugins for another application.  We have two directories each with the code it needs to run independently whcih contain all the dll's (but not the exe as its 3rd party and we have no control over it).  There is some shared code in a dll, placed in each plugin  directory.  When introducing a new version of the plugin we need to change this shared dll in one of the plugin directories but leave the other.  When we do this the old version breaks as it relies on the older version of the shared dll but it only loads one.  Is there a way to force it to use a certain version of the dll?

Answer (score 0):

you should use the latebinding approach `System.Reflection`

Comment: for anybody else looking at this we used strongly named assemblies with different versions.  different parts of the application were then able to use whichever assembly it needed based on the assembliy version it referenced.